# Is their a way to disable interaction on few polygons based on the property of a polygon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using `mapbox gl` with `mapbox-gl-draw` to render features as polygon on the map. I would like to change the polygon mode to `'STATIC'`(NO interaction on polygon) for only certain polygons that match a condition in the feature properties object.
Currently passing static mode to `draw-gl` component disables interaction on every polygon.

Example: The polygons which have `feature.properties.isDisabled == true` should have no interaction.

Comment: Without any code is hard to know how you are using mapbox-gl-draw and when the interaction could be skipped with code. As a base for selecting some features based on their properties, you can use [filter expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#filter) on `map.on('mousemove'` when you do the [`map.queryRenderedFeatures`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#queryrenderedfeatures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I know you can do this is to modify the interactive mode(s) of `mapbox-draw-gl` such that it checks for the specific feature property before allowing any interaction.

For example, the `simple_select` draw mode allows you to select, delete and drag features(polygons in this case). You can modify the `simple_select` mode to disable delete and drag interaction for features with `isDisabled` property by doing this:

```
const customSimpleSelectMode = () => {
   const SimpleSelectMode = MapboxDraw.modes.simple_select;

  const { dragMove: _dragMove, onTrash: _onTrash } = SimpleSelectMode;

  SimpleSelectMode.dragMove = function (...args) {
    const selectedFeatures = this.getSelected();
    if (selectedFeatures.some(feat => feat.properties.isDisabled)) return;

    _dragMove.apply(this, args);
  };

  SimpleSelectMode.onTrash = function (...args) {
    const selectedFeatures = this.getSelected();
    if (selectedFeatures.some(feat => feat.properties.isDisabled)) return;

    _onTrash.apply(this, args);
  };
  return SimpleSelectMode;
}
```

And when you're to instantiate a draw instance, do this:

```
const drawInstance = new MapboxDraw({
  modes: {
    ...MapboxDraw.modes,
    simple_select: customSimpleSelectMode,
  },
  // ...other config options
})
```

You can find the source code for the different draw modes [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/tree/main/src/modes).

This approach is in a way extending the standard Mapbox draw modes, you might have to lock the version of `mapbox-draw-gl` you are using in `package.json` so an update to the library won't break the extension.

**The downside to this approach:**

- You have to update every single draw mode that allows for any interaction you would like to disable. For polygons specifically, I know both `simple_select` and `direct_select` modes allow editing or deleting existing polygons so you would have to modify those two modes.